# Determine the lexicographical permutation your code is in

Tags: source-layout, code-bowling

<s>Write a program that outputs the number 0.</s>

That's a bit trivial, isn't it?

Let's sort all distinct permutations of your code in lexicographical order. When **any** of these codes are run, it should output the its location in the array (0-indexed or 1-indexed).

This means that your code must be the lexicographically smallest permutation of your code possible.

For example, if your code is `ABB`, then `ABB` -> 0; `BAB` -> 1; `BBA` -> 2.

### Rules

- Out of all distinct permutations of your code, it must be the lexicographically smallest.
- Your program must be at least **3** bytes long.
- "Output" represents any acceptable output: on the stack, to STDOUT, as a return value, as an exit code, etc.
- Your program is to not take any form of input.
- This is [code-bowling](/questions/tagged/code-bowling), so **longest** code wins.

Comment: The third is a fun challenge!

Comment: This seems really, really hard :)

Comment: @BaaingCow can we do it the other way around like `BBA -> 0`,  `BAB -> 1`, `ABB -> 2`, just like your specification of the previous challenge?

Comment: Wait a minute, does a Lenguage program that computes pi and then multiplies it by 0 work? (note: I plan to post an answer if that is okay)

Comment: If two permutations have the same value, can we treat it as the same permutation?

Comment: @petStorm I can't really see how would you distinguish between equal permutations :)

Comment: I think the score should be the number of distinct permutations, not the length.

Comment: It would be a good idea if you sandboxed your challenges instead of posting them right away... It would help you trim down the rough ends and help you create really neat challenges.

Comment: Love this! Am wondering for this and your previous 2 similar challenges, is one allowed to assume constant input? That is, have the input always set to some constant value, and have the rest of the code work partially by relying on it?

Comment: @AviF.S. I'm almost certain that is a standard loophole.

Comment: This really should have also had an irreducibility requirement added. That way, infinite answers would be so trivial.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too easy to get an infinitely large score, leaving the challenge effectively without an objective winning criterion.

Comment: I have to agree with @pppery. As it seems as though a majority of languages can get a "score = bytes" score, this essentially lacks a winning criteria

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), bytes = score

```
...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fT0/v/38A)

**How it works**: this program only has one distinct permutation and it outputs 0. It trivially satisfies all the other restrictions. The score can be made arbitrarily large by adding more `.`.

Comment: Can be extended indefinitely to be made arbitrarily large! Highly recommend adding `∞ bytes`. Also, perhaps clarifying that it outputs `ascii(0)`, rather than a literal `0`. Want to let you do as you see fit with it, but if you don't see this, I'll gladly make the edit for you! Unless, others chime in and think it a bad idea, but it seems to me fair game as it's still in the spirit of your answer!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), score = arbitrary

```python
000
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/38DA4P9/AA)

Returns through exit code, which is always `0`.
The source code is `0` repeated arbitrary many times. Since there's only 1 permutation of the source code, the permutation number is always `0`.

Answer (score 4):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), 548+++ bytes

```
#^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P9fOW4UjAL84P///wA)

This can also be just`#^^`. # prints and ^ increments. Please tell me if this is not lexicographic order, instead of downvoting.

Comment: Since this is infinitely expandable, you could just say "infinite" bytes.

Comment: Good job for having multiple distinct characters!

Comment: this might work in other stacked languages using many increments and one output

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), Arbitrarily large number of bytes.

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/99gFIyCUTDswf@C/wA)

No matter how many `0`s you write, it will leave a `0` on the stack, which is an acceptable output form for the challenge.  (The `p` in the TIO footer prints the stack so you can see what it is.)

Of course, the only permutation is the program itself.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 3 bytes (3 distinct permutations)

Outputs via unary, with a different set of output: `2 -> 3 -> 4`.

```
00\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/AIOb/fwA)

### Explanation

```
00\
00  Push 2 0's
  \ Swap (resuting in 2 0's)

0\0
0   Push 0
 \  Swap
  0 Push 0 (3 0's)

\00
\   Swap the empty stack (appends 2 0's)
 0  Push 0
  0 Push another 0 (resulting in 4 0's)
```

Comment: Uhh, I can't seem to find a permutation that outputs 6 zeroes.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate What about now? It seems that equivalent permutations are considered the same this time.